# React-Native, Firebase Realtime Database once/on/set not working

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a simple react-native app that already has authentication working. The issue is, I am unable to read/write to my firebase Realtime DB.

The once and on methods do not execute any callback (nether successful or failed) even when there is data in the DB. However, if I do a set operation, the on/once methods return values. None  of these values are reflected in the DB online, and these values do not persist when I delete the app data. Meaning, Realtime DB is only working locally, and not reflecting server side.

Notes:

- Realtime DB is in us-central1
- Rules are set to **true** for **read** and **write**
- `await reference.once('value')`  also did not work (never gets past this line)
- Able to get correct reference object as google-services.json contains firebase url (see code)
- I have firebase authentication working, so I am confident configuration steps are correct
- Have rebuilt the app and ran gradle build after any android related changes

**App.js:**

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const reference = database().ref('test');

    console.log(reference); // LOGS CORRECT ADDRESS

    reference.once(    // NO VALUE RETURNED
      'value',
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('error reading messages', error);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <IconComponentProvider IconComponent={MaterialCommunityIcons}>
      {/* <AppProvider>
        <NavigationStack />
      </AppProvider> */}
    </IconComponentProvider>
  );
};
```

**Realtime db values:**

```
{
  "test": "test"   // exported from parent level
}
```

**Realtime db rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.6.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.6.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/database": "^15.6.0",
  "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
  "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.4",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
  "eslint": "^7.32.0 || ^8.2.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
  "prettier": "^2.7.1",
  "react": "18.0.0",
  "react-native": "0.69.5",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
  "yarn": "^1.22.19"
},
```

**added app/build.gradle dependencies:**

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database"
```

**app permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to initialize the database with the explicit path to it:

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const db = firebase.app()
.database(
  'https://<databaseName>.<region>.firebasedatabase.app'
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this with no success.